# Reset auto increment for a column on a condition

Tags: mysql, rdbms

My application has session and question tables. Each question is mapped to a session.

I have a requirement in which i need to number the question incrementally starting from 1 for every new session. Is there a way in MySQL?

[image: Session Table]

[image: Questions Table]

Comment: You cannot reset the autoincrement. Just think what that would do to your existing rows on that table.

Comment: You do not provide enough information about what you are trying to achieve for us to give you a sensible alternative mechanism.

Comment: You could use a before insert trigger on the question to set the question number.

Comment: @RiggsFolly say i have multiple sessions of Q&A happening and the question number used for identification for each session has to start from 1.

Comment: Show us a little code, show us the schema for the relevant tables

Comment: @RiggsFolly i ve added the schema detail in the question.

Comment: i need to store the question number in the question table, which should start from 1 in every session